# iOS insert a entity but fetch the entity get no result

Tags: ios, core-data

I use Core Data for Data storage,but when I use method:

```
User *newUser = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                    [newUser setValue:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"jid"] forKey:@"jid"];
                    [newUser setValue:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"sid"] forKey:@"sid"];
                    [newUser setValue:[dataDictionary objectForKey:@"uid"] forKey:@"uid"];
```

I didn't get the delegate about the changes of moc(NSManagedContext) context.and after I saved the context by method :

```
 if (![moc save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"%@",error);
                }
```

but there was no error. when I fetch all entity "User" from the code,I get no result at all .

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"User"];

            [request setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"jid" ascending:YES]]];

            NSArray *result =(id)[socketHandler.dataManager.privateManagedObjectContext executeRequest:request error:&error];
            [result enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                User *user = obj;

            }];
```

in the terminal I get crash by result has 0 objects[image]

so ,what I misunderstand the Core Data framework? anyone help me ,I appreciate,Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you see you model in the xcdatamodel file, or you defined the managed model by code?

Comment: I define entity 'User' in xcdatamodel file ,and it has attributes:"jid","mid","uid".if I use [ObjectWithID:moid] method to fetch the specify managed object ,it can  get the User object ,but when I call user.jid . it return nil. I'm so confused by the CoreData Framework.